# Some JQuery Mobile touch events not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following code, and it seems clear that JQuery is working, but some JQuery Mobile events are not firing at all:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JQuery Mobile Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile.custom.complete.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.custom.complete.theme.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.custom.complete.structure.min.css"/>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $(document).on("touchstart", function(e){
                    $('#touchstart').html("touchstart");
                });
                $(document).on("touchend", function(e){
                    $('#touchend').html("touchend");
                });
                $(document).on("touchmove", function(e){
                    $('#touchmove').html("touchmove");
                });
                $(document).on("touchcancel", function(e){
                    $('#touchcancel').html("touchcancel");
                });
                $(document).on("tap", function(e){
                    $('#tap').html("tap");
                });
                $(document).on("taphold", function(e){
                    $('#taphold').html("taphold");
                });
                $(document).on("swipe", function(e){
                    $('#swipe').html("swipe");
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="touchstart">-</div>
        <div id="touchend">-</div>
        <div id="touchmove">-</div>
        <div id="touchcancel">-</div>
        <div id="tap">-</div>
        <div id="taphold">-</div>
        <div id="swipe">-</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying it out on Chrome on an Android. Of the above events, these don't work: `tap`, `taphold` and `swipe`. I have triple checked the file URLs.

The versions of JQuery above: JQuery: compressed, production 3.1.1,  and the latest JQuery Mobile: 1.4.5, custom with all options, minified.

Annoyingly **it works** as expected when I replace the link and script tags with a (random) earlier version, hosted by JQuery:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

And it **doesn't work** when I use the latest JQuery-hosted versions:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

But I need to host the files myself and I would like to have the latest versions. What am I doing wrong? Are there differences in the API? Or is it a JQuery bug?

Comment: It doesn't work with jQuery v3. Use older version of jQuery. Additionally, I don't recommend using a custom version of jQM; create your own touch events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Omar's comment above...
jQuery Mobile isn't compatible right now with the latest version of jQuery. If you look at the [jquerymobile homepage](http://jquerymobile.com), you will see under the download buttons (top-right) what versions of jQuery you can use. Currently for jQM v.1.4.5 you need:

> jQuery 1.8 - 1.11 / 2.1